# An algorithm to increase / decrease load in an application based on the number of exceptions

Tags: algorithm, distributed-system

I have a tonne of messages coming from a queue. Now, I want to dynamically vary the % of messages  that is being read and processed by  my application ( let's call it traffic %)
The parameters upon which i vary my traffic % is the number of messages failed to be processed ( errors ) by my application ( consumer of the queue )

If I hardcode something like, ' x errors in y mins (y can be fixed), reduce the traffic to z% '. Now after that, the traffic becomes low, the errors also become low. Need an algorithm, that takes into account the current traffic %, the number of errors and determines the new traffic %.  Traffic % range being 25% - 100%

Comment: Do you have any ideas how that algorithm could look like or any drafts?

Comment: Out of curiosity does message processing fail due to timeouts further into the chain?

Answer (score 1):

You take the inverse of the percent of errored messages to total messages within a time frame then you fit that percentage to your traffic range. This way if you get all errors your traffic percent would be 25% and if you get no errors your traffic percent would be 100%.

```
// traffic% 25%
minTraffic = 0.25
// traffic% 100%
maxTraffic = 1.00
// 25% -> 100% is a usable range of 75%
deltaTraffic = maxTraffic - minTraffic
// use Max(total, 1) to avoid divide by zero
error = (erroredMessagesPerTimeFrame / Math.max(totalMessagesPerTimeFrame, 1))
// inverse: error=1.00 becomes 0, error=0.00 becomes 1
invError = 1 - pcError
// linear clamp invError to [minTraffic, maxTraffic]
traffic = minTraffic + (deltaTraffic * invError)
```

This is the simplest implementation using a linear fit.

An alternate version might fit your "invError" value to the "deltaTraffic" using a curve instead, this would weigh higher and lower values closer (or further) to your "minTraffic" and "maxTraffic" depending on what type of curve you use.

Another alternative would be to just use a step function

```
If "invError" < 50% Then "minTraffic" 
Else If "invError" < 75% Then "minTraffic" + (("maxTraffic" - "minTraffic") / 2)
Else "maxTraffic"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is called the Circuit Breaker design pattern. You can find good information all over; some top search results are [here](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html), [here](https://hackernoon.com/introduction-to-circuit-breaker-pattern-how-to-build-better-software-d11g3t7g) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/circuit-breaker).

In essence, you're implementing a little state machine that may limit the number of requests depending on errors. You can have two or three states depending on if you want also want just cut off the flow or also want to throttle the flow rate for a small period.

You may also want to look at [single-rate or dual-rate leaky buckets](https://blog.ine.com/2011/05/22/understanding-single-rate-and-dual-rate-traffic-policing), which have been in use in the networking controllers for ages.

---

Here is the Microsoft implementation of the state machine. They (and the other sources)
suggest you make a generic *adaptor* to wrap your code and separate the concerns.

```
...
    if (IsOpen)
    {
      // The circuit breaker is Open. Check if the Open timeout has expired.
      // If it has, set the state to HalfOpen. Another approach might be to
      // check for the HalfOpen state that had be set by some other operation.
      if (stateStore.LastStateChangedDateUtc + OpenToHalfOpenWaitTime < DateTime.UtcNow)
      {
        // The Open timeout has expired. Allow one operation to execute. Note that, in
        // this example, the circuit breaker is set to HalfOpen after being
        // in the Open state for some period of time. An alternative would be to set
        // this using some other approach such as a timer, test method, manually, and
        // so on, and check the state here to determine how to handle execution
        // of the action.
        // Limit the number of threads to be executed when the breaker is HalfOpen.
        // An alternative would be to use a more complex approach to determine which
        // threads or how many are allowed to execute, or to execute a simple test
        // method instead.
        bool lockTaken = false;
        try
        {
          Monitor.TryEnter(halfOpenSyncObject, ref lockTaken);
          if (lockTaken)
          {
            // Set the circuit breaker state to HalfOpen.
            stateStore.HalfOpen();

            // Attempt the operation.
            action();

            // If this action succeeds, reset the state and allow other operations.
            // In reality, instead of immediately returning to the Closed state, a counter
            // here would record the number of successful operations and return the
            // circuit breaker to the Closed state only after a specified number succeed.
            this.stateStore.Reset();
            return;
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          // If there's still an exception, trip the breaker again immediately.
          this.stateStore.Trip(ex);

          // Throw the exception so that the caller knows which exception occurred.
          throw;
        }
        finally
        {
          if (lockTaken)
          {
            Monitor.Exit(halfOpenSyncObject);
          }
        }
      }
      // The Open timeout hasn't yet expired. Throw a CircuitBreakerOpen exception to
      // inform the caller that the call was not actually attempted,
      // and return the most recent exception received.
      throw new CircuitBreakerOpenException(stateStore.LastException);
    }
    ...
```